# Reading feature names from a csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file looks like

```
        F1    F2    F3
 A1      2     4     2
 A2      4     1     2
```

When I read the file using pandas, I see that the first column is unnamed.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
features = df.columns
print( features )

Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'F1, 'F2, 'F3'])
```

In fact I want to get only F1, F2 and F3. I can fix that with some array manipulation. But I want to know if pandas has some builtin capabilities to do that. Any thought?

**UPDATE:**

Using `index_col = False` or `None` doesn't work either.

[image]

Comment: Please see the updated post

Comment: What is the delimiter between fields in your `csv` file?

Comment: It is comma. The file looks like `,F1,F2,F3 \\ A1,2,4,2 \\ A2,4,1,2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That unnamed is only because of index column being read, you can use the `index_col = [0]` argument in the read statement to resolve.

This picks the first column as index instead of a feature itself.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col=[0])
features = df.columns
print( features )

Index(['F1', 'F2', 'F3'])
```

Comment: @manmood, this is now because your first column is not even index, will edit this answer to help.

Comment: Check the edited answer, try this one please!

Comment: Correct. But it seems that I am not able to get the first column which it my observations. I mean `y = df.loc[:,0].values` should be A1 and A2.

Comment: @mahmood, we are converting it to the index, if you need it ad a column, you would need to have a name to the column instead of Unnamed:0.

Comment: @mahmood, if you need A1, A2, you could use df.index

Comment: I understand, but I would like to get the feature list `['F1', 'F2, 'F3']` and target list `['A1', 'A2']` in two separate arrays.

Comment: Make `targets = list(df.index)`, for getting that array. @mahmood